# Using HTTP PUT to send JSON with Jquery and Rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, http, rest

HTTP PUT isn't entirely cross browser so Rails (I'm using Rails 3) supports using POST and passing the `_method` query param.  This is great, but it doesn't seem to work when sending JSON.

**Example:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: window.location.pathname,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({_method:'PUT', page:{my_data: 1}),
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

When Rails sees this, it doesn't recognize the '_method' override because it's passed in the JSON format (perhaps that conversion is later?).  Rails returns an error "No route matches ..." saying it can't find the route (to the resource), I assume because it doesn't match the REST update=HTTP PUT verb, I've even tried appending this to the URL: `?_method=PUT` but got the same result.

The only thing that *does* seem to work is setting an HTTP header:

```
$.ajax({
    url: window.location.pathname,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({my_data: 1}),
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Http-Method-Override","put");
    }
});
```

**Is setting the HTTP override header the best way?**

Comment: It looks like most web browsers 4 years ago supported setting the method directly (PUT POST DELETE for XmlHTTPRequests), so it's safe to say it works just fine without setting the extra header, or the `_method` parameter.  My original error was caused by mixing up PUT / POST when routing to rails.It looks like most web browsers 4 years ago supported this (PUT POST DELETE for XmlHTTPRequests), so it's safe to say it works just fine.  My original error was caused by mixing up PUT / POST when routing to rails.

Comment: Did you ever figure out why the top version doesn't work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AJAX supports the `PUT` verb directly so why bothering with `_method` and custom HTTP headers:

```
$.ajax({
    url: window.location.pathname,
    type: 'PUT',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ page: { my_data: 1 }),
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Also make sure you are respecting the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) or jquery might try to use JSONP which works only with `GET` verbs.

Comment: Not all browsers support `PUT` and `DELETE` methods in XmlHTTPRequest, but if you target modern ones go with it.

Comment: HTTP spec describes PUT, POST, ...  AJAX is just a collection of technologies.  Though, you seem to be right (after much looking around) that *most* modern browsers support HTTP PUT.

Comment: It looks like most web browsers 4 years ago supported this (PUT POST DELETE for XmlHTTPRequests), so it's safe to say it works just fine.  My original error was caused by mixing up PUT / POST when routing to rails.